# combine arrays and concat value?

Tags: php, foreach

Little complex to explain , so here is simple concrete exemple :

array 1 :

```
Array
(
    [4] => bim
    [5] => pow
    [6] => foo 
)
```

array 2 :

```
Array
    (
        [n] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [m] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )

        [l] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 64
            )
```

And i need to output an array 3 ,

array expected :

```
Array
        (
            [bim] => n-1
            [pow] => Array
                (
                    [0] => m-1
                    [1] => m-2
                )

            [foo] => Array
                (
                    [0] => l-1
                    [1] => l-4
                    [2] => l-64
                )
```

Final echoing OUTPUT expected:

bim n-1 , pow m-1 m-2 ,foo l-1 l-4 l-64 ,

I tried this but seems pity:

```
foreach($array2 as $k1 =>$v1){

            foreach($array2[$k1] as $k => $v){
            $k[] =  $k1.'_'.$v);
             }



foreach($array1 as $res =>$val){

            $val = $array2;

            }
```

Thanks for helps,
Jess

Comment: So the format should be same always means if first array is having 3 elements then 2nd will have exactly 3, and first element from 1st array will be always associated with the first element in the 2nd to generate the final array ?

Comment: The code you tried won't even compile. There's a `)` too much in the second for-each and you're missing a `;` in the last for-each.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty if i understand well , answer is yes

Comment: @BastiM i edited but unfortunatly its not the pb..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet

```
<?php
 $a=array(4=>'bim',5=>'pow',6=>'foo');
 $b=array('n'=>array(1),'m'=>array(1,2),'l'=>array(1,4,64));
 $keys=array_values($a);
 $values=array();
 foreach($b as $key=>$value)
 {
   if(is_array($value) && !empty($value))
   {
 foreach($value as $k=>$val)
 {
    if($key=='n')
    {
        $values[$key]=$key.'-'.$val;
    }
    else
    {
        $values[$key][]=$key.'-'.$val;
    }
  }
 }
}

$result=array_combine($keys,$values);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: yes ok, but with ur solution, how do you make the Final echoing OUTPUT expected:

bim n-1 , pow m-1 m-2 ,foo l-1 l-4 l-64

Comment: I have used array_combine function for generating final result which creates a new array with keys and values as arguements

Answer (score 2):

CHALLENGE ACCEPTED

```
<?php

$a = array(
    4 => 'bim', 
    5 => 'pow', 
    6 => 'foo',
);
$b = array(
    'n' => array(1),
    'm' => array(1, 2),
    'l' => array(1, 4, 64),
);

$len = count($a);
$result = array();

$aVals = array_values($a);
$bKeys = array_keys($b);
$bVals = array_values($b);

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $combined = array();
    $key = $aVals[$i];
    $prefix = $bKeys[$i];
    $items = $bVals[$i];

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $combined[] = sprintf('%s-%d', $prefix, $item);
    };

    if (count($combined) === 1) {
        $combined = $combined[0];
    }

    $result[$key] = $combined;
}

var_dump($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code may be very easy. For example, assuming arrays:

```
$one = Array
(
    4 => 'bim',
    5 => 'pow',
    6 => 'foo'
);

$two = Array
(
        'n' => Array
            (
                0 => 1
            ),

        'm' => Array
            (
                0 => 1,
                1 => 2
            ),

        'l' => Array
            (
                0 => 1,
                1 => 4,
                2 => 64
            )
);
```

You may get your result with:

```
$result = [];
while((list($oneKey, $oneValue) = each($one)) &&
      (list($twoKey, $twoValue) = each($two)))
{
   $result[$oneValue] = array_map(function($item) use ($twoKey)
   {
      return $twoKey.'-'.$item;
   }, $twoValue);
};
```

-check this [demo](http://3v4l.org/nPa4W#v540) Note, that code above will not make single-element array as single element. If that is needed, just add:

```
$result = array_map(function($item)
{
   return count($item)>1?$item:array_shift($item);
}, $result);
```

Version of this solution for `PHP4>=4.3`, `PHP5>=5.0` you can find [here](http://3v4l.org/qPd1E)

*Update:* if you need only string, then use [this](http://3v4l.org/OncQd) (cross-version):

```
$result = array();
while((list($oneKey, $oneValue) = each($one)) &&
      (list($twoKey, $twoValue) = each($two)))
{
   $temp = array();
   foreach($twoValue as $item)
   {
       $temp[] = $twoKey.'-'.$item;
   }
   $result[] = $oneValue.' '.join(' ', $temp);
};
$result = join(' ', $result);
```

Comment: But it requires php 5.3, Miraages doesn't :P

Comment: thx for answer but i don't see how ajust it for my case, do you have the concret exmple with my arrays ?!

Comment: So what? My solution requires at least 5.4 (because of `[]` array declaration). Again: don't be stuck with old PHP versions. There are no reasons to use them. If you will not use shared hostings - you may forget about old PHP versions at all

Comment: NO. "[bim] => n-1" - not array, your solution is array.

Comment: @Alma Do Well, I agree completely but let's say for example debian. I don't know if it has updated the repository by now but last time I checked they didn't offer PHP 5.3. My point is: No matter how dare you want the new PHP, some people simply *can't* get it, at least not at appropiate costs (some even have to pay for an upgrade maybe D: ).

Comment: @Matmarbon actually, that's a poor excuse. All modern repo-s offer new versions. If you'll be stuck with old versions, you'll never develop your knowledge. But, actually, if that's about code above, the only thing that is needed is to replace callback with `create_function()`.

Comment: Actualy its the case, i'm on debian, my php version seems not enought for this solution ..:(

Comment: yes ok, but with ur solution, how do you make the Final echoing OUTPUT expected:

bim n-1 , pow m-1 m-2 ,foo l-1 l-4 l-64

Comment: What do you mean "final output"? I.e. you don't want array, but some string?

Comment: i mean as i wrote in the question, my final result should be in this form :
bim n-1 , pow m-1 m-2 ,foo l-1 l-4 l-64

Comment: thanks, to be honestly i don't know what is the best solution between yours and Rubin Porwal solution

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind should be clear by reading the code comments.
Here's a [demo @ PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6xd-bwv).

```
//omitted array declarations
$output = array();

//variables to shorten things in the loop
$val1 = array_values($array1);
$keys2 = array_keys($array2);
$vals2 = array_values($array2);

//iterating over each element of the first array
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    //if the second array has multiple values at the same index
    //as the first array things will be handled differently
    if(count($vals2[$i]) > 1) {         
        $tempArr = array();     

        //iterating over each element of the second array
        //at the specified index
        foreach($vals2[$i] as $val) {
            //we push each element into the temporary array
            //(in the form of "keyOfArray2-value"
            array_push($tempArr, $keys2[$i] . "-" . $val);
        }

        //finally assign it to our output array
        $output[$val1[$i]] = $tempArr;
    } else {
        //when there is only one sub-element in array2
        //we can assign the output directly, as you don't want an array in this case
        $output[$val1[$i]] = $keys2[$i] . "-" . $vals2[$i][0];
    }

}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
  ["bim"]=> "n-1" 
  ["pow"]=> Array (
    [0]=> "m-1" 
    [1]=> "m-2" 
  ) 
  ["foo"]=> Array ( 
    [0]=> "l-1" 
    [1]=> "l-4" 
    [2]=> "l-64" 
  ) 
)
```

Concerning your final output you may do something like

```
$final = "";
//$output can be obtained by any method of the other answers,
//not just with the method i posted above
foreach($output as $key=>$value) {
    $final .= $key . " ";
    if(count($value) > 1) {
        $final .= implode($value, " ") .", ";
    } else {
        $final .= $value . ", ";
    }
}

$final = rtrim($final, ", ");
```

This will echo `bim n-1, pow m-1 m-2, foo l-1 l-4 l-64`.